# Using Twitter4j, how do I filter using the statuses/sample and by a filter query?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

How do I first get all the sample tweets from “GET statuses/sample” and then filter by a word?

I tried chaining as well but that didn't seem to work:
e.g. twitterStream.sample.filter(new FilterQuery("Microsoft")

```
        TwitterStreamFactory tf = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build());
        TwitterStream twitterStream = tf.getInstance();
        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        twitterStream.sample():
        twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery("Microsoft"));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this : stackoverflow.com/questions/16665683/filter-twitter4j-stream